# osm2pgsql: Failed to fork helper process

Tags: osm2pgsql, amazon-ec2

I am trying to import planet.osm on am Amazon EC2 machine. It is a a machine with 16 processors and 122GB RAM.

The parameters I use are: `osm2pgsql -s -H aws.rds.host -d osm -U user -C 92000 --number-processes 16 --cache-strategy dense --hstore --hstore-add-index -K -G -W -p osm --extra-attributes -v planet.osm.pbf`

However, after the processing phase I get the following error:

```
WARNING: Failed to fork helper process 1: Trying to recover.
WARNING: Failed to fork helper process 2: Trying to recover.
...
WARNING: Failed to fork helper process 15: Trying to recover.
```

There is another question here with a memory issue (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78879/osm-problem-with-memory), but this is not the error I get. There is no mention of "Cannot allocate memory".

Does anyone know of these issues or have any experience importing on EC2 machines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are hitting https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/issues/90 (i.e. this is a known issue on EC2).

A possible reason is that your cache size is way too high. Based on the [osm2pgsql instructions](https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql#usage), you should be using 24000.

Not specific to your question, but if you intend to render off this, remember that EC2 isn't a great database solution: see http://blog.gravitystorm.co.uk/2010/07/05/map-rendering-on-ec2/ for one user's experience.